# Jquery plugin usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I think I'm being really stupid here. I'm trying to call a method using a plugin I've already instantiated against a div element.

The plugin is using the boiler plate as defined here

http://jqueryboilerplate.com/

The plugin works and I instantiate it using the following

```
calendar = $('#calendar').Calendar({'weekStart': 1,'startDate':startDate,'endDate':endDate});
```

Some point later when an event is called I want to call a method in that plugin but the life of me I can't figure it out.

I've tried all manor of different approaches, my latest unsuccessful one was

```
var thing = $('#calendar');
thing.Calendar.redraw({'startDate':startDate,'endDate':endDate});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Try $('#calendar').Calendar('myMethod')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, thanks to Bouillou who pointed me in the right direction.

```
$('#calendar').data('plugin_Calendar').redraw({'startDate':startDate,'endDate':endDate});
```